# I'm getting this Error when installing shared_preferences in my Flutter Project

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

[image]When I installed shared_preferences into my flutter project, always getting this error. can help me? or another alternative to save token like global value.

[image]

Comment: Did you try to `flutter clean` your project?

Comment: Did you try to run the project  through xcode.

Comment: Yeah, see above

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use the following steps and see whether the errors still exist or not.

1. cd ios
2. pod deintegrate
3. flutter clean
4. flutter pub cache repair
5. flutter pub get
6. pod install
7. pod repo update
8. flutter run

Try to run these command

Comment: Those commands inside iOS folder? @Wei Long

Comment: I have already tried these steps and it is still the same.